# How to apply multiple filters to sort a nested python dictionary items by their sub-values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to apply multiple filters to sort a nested python dictionary items by their sub-values and save that dictionary items in descending order

I have a dictionary which is described below:

```
my_dict={
         "Bob": {"Buy": 25, "Sell": 33, "Quantity": 268},
         "Moli": {"Buy": 75, "Sell": 53, "Quantity": 300},
         "Annie": {"Buy": 74, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 96},
         "Anna": {"Buy": 55, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 154},
         "Ammi": {"Buy": 66, "Sell": 75, "Quantity": 366},
         "Kayle": {"Buy": 59, "Sell": 63, "Quantity": 257}
        }
```

I want to apply multiple filters in same line to sort dictionary items in descending order where sub- values("Buy") is greater than 30 by their sub- values("Quantity")

Example:

Sort nested dictionary where  sub- values("Buy")>30 and sub- values("Quantity") in descending order

Just like we short in Pandas dataframe

```
pandas_sorted_dictionary = my_dict[my_dict.Buy > 30].sort_values("Quantity", ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
```

how to add same filter which is described above (i.e: pandas_sorted_dictionary) in my filter which is described below (i.e: dictionary_sorted_dictionary)

```
dictionary_sorted_dictionary = dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda v: v[1]['Quantity'], reverse=True))
```

Expected Output:

```
dictionary_sorted_dictionary={
                              "Ammi": {"Buy": 66, "Sell": 75, "Quantity": 366},
                              "Moli": {"Buy": 75, "Sell": 53, "Quantity": 300},
                              "Kayle": {"Buy": 59, "Sell": 63, "Quantity": 257},
                              "Anna": {"Buy": 55, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 154},
                              "Annie": {"Buy": 74, "Sell": 83, "Quantity": 96},
                             }
```

Answer (score 1):

The sort can be done using `sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["Quantity"], reverse=True)`, and the `Buy>30` can be applied using dict comprehension. The overall query would look like:

```
result = {i[0]:i[1] for i in sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["Quantity"], reverse=True) if i[1]["Buy"]>30}
```